# SSRS not displaying the tooltip correctly

Tags: reporting-services, tooltip, field

I have a problem in my staked bar chart, the tooltip is working only for the first line serie, contrariwise in every other bar it shows "Report Char".

It should display the value of the associated serie, in my case I use for the first bar:

```
=Fields!AlertsVal.Value
```

Which is a calculated value of the dataset

```
= IIF( Fields!Category.Value = "Alert", Fields!Value.Value, Nothing)
```

And for the second, that is not working:

```
= Round( Fields!WarningVal.Value, 1 ).ToString & "Warnings"

= IIF( Fields!Category.Value = "Warning", Fields!Value.Value, Nothing)
```

They seem to be the same but for the second it doesn't work

I also tried to display the sum as:

```
=Sum(Fields!WarningVal.Value, "TestDataset")
```

And in this way it works but I don't need the sum.

[Problem Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2H6OL.png)